# Versioning and Roll-Back in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, versioning

Is there a way to version changes and do roll-backs in Marketing Cloud.

We want to do versioning and roll-backs on Cloud Pages and Email Content.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't anything like that in Marketing Cloud.  There are some undo options in Journey Builder, but nothing formal in Cloud Pages and Email Content.

You can pull Marketing Cloud assets with the API -- for those objects that are retrievable -- and store them in source control outside of the platform. Our team does that.  On projects that don't warrant that scale, we just manually store copy and paste content from SFMC into files.

This might sound like a pain, but it's not that much overhead for what you gain if you have a larger team.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that currently.  I actually just submitted an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TthqQAC) this afternoon for the same thing.  Be sure to upvote the idea. Once ideas get up to enough points then they get evaluated as possible product updates.