# CloudPages - hosting HTML on either GitHub, DropBox, etc. - and HTTPGet into a CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm trying to figure out how to be able to host HTML files within either GitHub or DropBox, then perform an HTTPGet within a CloudPage like below:

```
%%[
    set @httpContent = HTTPGet('https://www.dropbox.com/s/0og6dbz3hbyqf1h/test.html')
]%%

%%=TreatAsContent(@httpContent)=%%
```

The expectation which I'm having trouble with is that I would like to be able to edit these HTML files in real time, and by doing so, the CloudPage will always be updated with the most recent changes.  Basically, if you consider the DropBox file above (test.html), I would want to go to DropBox, edit the file, save it, then immediately via the AMPScript above in the CloudPage, the CloudPage will be updated with the updated test.html.  I hope that makes sense.  When you run the following CloudPage URL which contains the code above:

https://cloud.email.travelers.com/welcome

It literally pulls in the actual HTML rather than rendering it.  Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I think TreatAsContent forces evaluation of AMPscript, not rendering of HTML. Have you tried fitting all your html into an ampscript variable? Eg. `%%[ set @html = “...all html goes here” Output(v(@html)) ]%%` and then doing the rest like you did?

Comment: You should try [this solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337020/connect-smfc-to-github/337057#337057), which I use on a daily basis to update Cloud Page code in real time.